# Calling Xtext generator from an Eclipse View

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext, xtend

I'm planning to generate code by calling the generator from a button located in an Eclipse View, similar to this approach:

https://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/xtext-calling-the-generator-from-a-context-menu/,

but instead of calling the generator from the context menu I want to call it with a click on a button, like the following code shows:

```
    button1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            // Call GenerationHandler here
        }

        ...
    });
```

The Problem is, I can't simply call the execute-Method in the `GenerationHandler` as shown below:

```
public class GenerationHandler extends AbstractHandler implements IHandler {

@Inject private IGenerator generator; 
@Inject private Provider<EclipseResourceFileSystemAccess> fileAccessProvider;

@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException { 
    ...
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
}
```

And I'm not sure how to make an Handler, that I can access form the button.So the question is, is there a way to access the Handler from the `SelectionListener` `widgetSelected()` method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `IHandlerService` to execute the command that the handler handles:

```
IHandlerService handlerService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getService(IHandlerService.class);

handlerService.executeCommand("your command id", null);
```